# Install Tomcat Server 8 on Eclipse Luna running on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, apache2, eclipse

I faced issues while installing Tomcat server v8 on eclipse, I followed following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250835/how-to-add-apache-tomcat-7-in-eclipse-luna)

But when I go to help-> install software, and select any site in work with, I get as `There are no categorized items`.

What should I do to install tomcat server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out there is an easy way of doing that. You can follow this blog post which is providing a step by step guide to do it : [Install Apache Tomcat on Ubuntu](http://www.javahelps.com/2015/03/install-apache-tomcat-on-ubuntu.html)

**Step 1:**
Open the Eclipse.

**Step 2:**
Goto Windows → Preferences in the menu bar and select the Runtime Environments under the Server.

[image]

**Step 3:**
Click on the 'Add' button.

**Step 4:**
Select your Apache Tomcat version under the 'Apache' root and click 'Next'.

[image]

**Step 5:**
Browse and select the Tomcat installation directory.

[image]

**Step 6:**
Click on the 'Finish' button

**Step 7:**
Click on the 'OK' button to close the Preferences dialog.

[image]